# What value does 1/sqrt(n) approach?

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, self-learning

Intuitively I would say 0 but I want to get a second opinion.
We know that $\frac{1}{n}$ approaches 0, as n goes to infinity.

We also know that $\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{1}{n}$ diverges.
We also know that $\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ diverges by the integral test and "direct comparison" test.

How can we conclude anything about the limit from this knowledge about the limit of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ ?

When I plot it I can see it approaching zero but how can I proove it ?

Comment: How about: $1/\sqrt{n}$ is decreasing with $n$, and the subsequence $(1/\sqrt{n})_{n=k^2,k=1}^{\infty} = (1/k)_{k=1}^{\infty}$ converges to zero. So the whole sequence must converge to zero.

Comment: That is not a "good" argument. The sequence $(1,1,1,...)$ is a convergent subsequence of $(1,-1,1,-1,..)$, but  $(1,-1,1,-1,..)$ is divergent.

Comment: @Fred With the mentioned monotonicity, that *is* a good argument. But it's definitely overkill for this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use that $\sqrt{\cdot}$ is continuous at $0$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} = 0$. Then we get $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} = \sqrt{\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}} = \sqrt{0} = 0.
$$

Answer (score 6):

From the divergence of $\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ we can deduce nothing, but:

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}=|\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-0|< \epsilon$ $\iff n > \frac{1}{\epsilon^2}$.

Can you now see that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \to 0$ for $n \to \infty$ ?

Comment: I dont understand the significance of $\epsilon$ in this context, can you elaborate a little or point me to a resource ?

Comment: @zython This is just the definition of a sequence having a limit. Here $\varepsilon > 0$.

Comment: @zython Do you know the definition of limit of a sequence?

Comment: @SahibaArora I have seen the epsilon delta criterium before but couldnt understand how its being used here and in general

Comment: How do you show limit of $\frac 1n$ is $0$